# declare a class member function to use before linking

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I want to use a class which is present in other module and would be available in linking. Size of header file is huge so I don't want to include header in current module.

I am trying to forward declare class by

> > class foo;
> >       int foo::getValue();

here getValue() is member function of foo that I want to use.

Now when I am compiling my code I got compilation error before linking as

`error: forward declaration of 'struct foo'`

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: You might consider the Pimpl idiom. See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't forward declare class members, you'll need to include the whole header.

The correct approach here is to reduce the size of the header. If it only contains the class definition, leave it as it is. If not, there's potential to break it into multiple headers.

If the class definition is huge, that'a a sign your design is faulty and could be broken up.

Answer (score 0):

A forward declaration of a classes may only be used when you do not need knowledge of the internal structure of the class, i.e. members and/or size.

The typical use of this technique involves class pointers or references:

```
class included_class;

class encapsulating_class
{
  public:
    void some_method(const& included_class_pointer) const;
  private:
    included_class * included_class_pointer;
};
```

Attempting to forward declare class internals in the way that you indicated is not possible using this technique and requires inclusion of the class header.